# How to add and remove class of an element by clicking on other? in React-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I want to toggle class of a element by clicking another element in React-Redux.

Comment: You may have a reason to use redux, but you might also be able to solve this using component state without adding complexity to your store.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this problem, follow following steps to do this:

Element where click is done:

```
    class readMore extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {classToSend: true };
    }

    stateToRender(){
        (this.state.classToSend) ? this.setState({classToSend: false}) : this.setState({classToSend: true});
    }

    onClickHandler(){
        this.stateToRender();
        this.props.readMore(this.state.classToSend);
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div onClick={() => this.onClickHandler()}
                className="readmore">
                <div className="readmore-btn">Read more</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Action creator:

```
export function readMore(class_something) {

    return {
        type: READ_MORE,
        payload: class_something
    };

}
```

Reducer:

```
export default function (state="", action) {

    switch(action.type){

        case READ_MORE:

            return action.payload;
    }

    return state;
}
```

Other element where class is supposed to change:

```
export class XYZ extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    renderClassNames(){
        let classname = "slide-tourInfo";

        if (this.props.readMore) {
            classname += " slide-tourInfo-scale";
        }

        return classname;
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div className = {this.renderClassNames()}>

            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
   export default class MyClass extends Component{

        constructor(props){
            super(props);

            this.state {
                toggleClass: false
            }
        }

        toggleFunction = () => {
            this.setState({toggleClass: !this.state.toggleClass})
        }

        render(){
            return(
                <div>
                    <button onClick={this.toggleFunction}>ClickMe</button>
                    <div className={this.state.toggleClass?'classOnTrue':'classOnFalse'}></div>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is not through redux. You are changing state locally.

Answer (score 0):

For a redux implementation you would dispatch an action on the click event from the first element; the second element would have its class derived from the state (one of its *props*) so that when this changes in response to the click it re-renders with the new class name.

Idiomatic usage would probably have both elements wrapped in a container component that orchestrated the props and dispatched events; usually using the *connect* method.